# Make ejabberd Ignore AWS ELB Proxy Protocol Header

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, cluster-computing, ejabberd, amazon-elb

I have an ejabberd cluster behind an elastic load balancer on AWS. In order to support sticky sessions for clients, I'm trying to configure the ELB for proxy protocol. However, as expected, that inserts a proxy line at the top of the xml stanza that is sent to ejabberd node, which then rejects it with an error "xml-not-well-formed" back to the client.

Can someone advise please what should be the best way here to modify ejabberd so that it doesn't consider the incoming stanza as ill-formed? Appreciate your inputs - afraid my limited ejabberd and Erlang understanding isn't helping me at all!

Comment: I can think of no connection between the proxy protocol and ELB sticky sessions, which are an HTTP (not TCP) feature of ELB.  All it does is communicate the source/target address/port in-band, using the `PROXY` message, which you do not seem to want or need, so please clarify why you have enabled it, the desired result, and how this gets you there... perhaps with a link to something in the documentation or a tutorial you're using... because it's not clear that your proposed modification would actually yield any benefit.

Comment: Hi @Michael-sqlbot - thanks for getting back. So essentially, my chat clients (with ejabberd as the server) keep getting timed out of their sessions when I put an ELB in front of the cluster of ejabberd nodes. I understood that is due to the same node not getting reused for maintaining the XMPP stream with the client when we use an ELB, hence the time-out. To address that, I enabled sticky sessions - but as you mention, that doesn't address TCP/SSL, so I further enabled the Proxy Protocol. That, from what I understand, sends a TCP header, which ejabberd doesn't recognize.

Comment: Hence I'm trying to find out how to modify the ejabberd server code to either ignore this header, or parse it appropriately, which would be separate to what the ELB does to ensure stickiness... hope I could explain...

Comment: Okay, but enabling the proxy protocol has nothing at all to do with stickiness.  And stickiness will not fix a timeout, because you still have to reconnect and renegotiate.  If you need a longer timeout, at the risk of asking the obvious, did you try [increasing the timeout on the ELB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/config-idle-timeout.html)?  The default is only 60 seconds.

Comment: Oh ok. I thought that enabling stickiness (did change its timeout to 900 secs) would make the ELB reconnect and renegotiate, and that enabling the proxy protocol is just to help with the TCP bit... any ideas that you might have?